# Display result not working - no records returned

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue in a program and cannot figure out how to fix it. I believe the problem is with the way I am trying to put the output of a report - having the ID # shown, then name: lastname, firstname when a report is run by having the Sys.out.print line say "Student name " + array[2] + array[1].

How do I go about fixing this issue?  It only occurs when I try to run the report.  The text file that is created when entering a student's information is done correctly.

/**
 * Filename: LowerAndUpperDisplay.java 
 * Created: Oct 31 2013
 * Created By : 
 * Purpose: Expand the LowerAndUpper application so that it disp`enter code here`lays each record one by one
 * from the lowerclassman file and then from the upperclassman file. 
 * Display heading to introduce each list. 
 * 
 * For each record, display the ID number, first name, last name, credits earned, and number 
 * of additional credits needed to graduate. Assume that 120 credits are required for graduation.
 */

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LowerAndUpperDisplay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Path lowerClassmanFile = Paths.get("C:/temp/lowerclassman.txt");

        Path upperClassmanFile = Paths.get("C:/temp/upperclassman.txt");

        char choice;

        int idNum;

        int totalCredits;

        String first;

        String last;

        String classStanding = " ";

        try

        {
            OutputStreamWriter lWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(
                            lowerClassmanFile, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)));

            BufferedWriter lowerClassmanWriter = new BufferedWriter(lWriter);

            OutputStreamWriter uWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(
                            upperClassmanFile, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)));

            BufferedWriter upperClassmanWriter = new BufferedWriter(uWriter);

            do {

                System.out
                        .print("Student Records "
                                + "\nTo enter student records, type S.  For a report, type R.  To exit, type Q.");

                choice = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

                switch (choice)

                {
                case 'S':

                    System.out.println("Please enter student information.");

                    System.out.print("ID Number: ");

                    idNum = input.nextInt();

                    input.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("First Name: ");

                    first = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("Last Name: ");

                    last = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Credit Hours Earned: ");

                    totalCredits = input.nextInt();

                    input.nextLine();

                    classStanding = "ID Number " + idNum + ", Student Name: "
                            + last + ", " + first + " Credit Hours: "
                            + totalCredits;

                    if (totalCredits >= 60) {

                        upperClassmanWriter.write(classStanding);

                        upperClassmanWriter.newLine();
                    }

                    else {

                        lowerClassmanWriter.write(classStanding);

                        lowerClassmanWriter.newLine();
                    }

                    break;

                case 'R':

                    try {

                        InputStreamReader lReader = new InputStreamReader(
                                new BufferedInputStream(Files
                                        .newInputStream(lowerClassmanFile)));

                        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(lReader);

                        InputStreamReader uReader = new InputStreamReader(
                                new BufferedInputStream(Files
                                        .newInputStream(upperClassmanFile)));

                        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(uReader);

                        System.out
                                .print("The lower classmen are:  ");

                        classStanding = reader1.readLine();

                        String[] array;

                        while (classStanding != null) {

                            array = classStanding.split(",");

                            totalCredits = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);

                            System.out.print("ID Number " + array[0]);

                            System.out.print("Student name " + array[2] + ", " + array[1]) ;

                            System.out.print("Total credits: " + totalCredits);

                            System.out.print("This student is " + (120 - totalCredits) 
                                    + " credits short of earning their degree.");

                            classStanding = reader1.readLine();

                        }// end while

                        reader1.close();

                        System.out.print("The upper classmen are:  ");

                        classStanding = reader2.readLine();

                        while (classStanding != null) {

                            array = classStanding.split(",");

                            totalCredits = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);

                            //System.out.format("Student Id Number :", "");

                            System.out.print("ID Number " + array[0]);

                            System.out.print("Student name : " + array[2] + ", " + array[1]);

                            System.out.print("Total credits: " + totalCredits);

                            System.out.print("This student is  " + (120 - totalCredits) 
                                    + "credits short of earning their degree.");

                            classStanding = reader2.readLine();

                        }// end while

                        reader2.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("Message: " + e);

                    }
                case 'Q':

                    break;

                default:

                    System.out
                            .printf("You have made an invalid option.  Please enter a valid option. \n");

                }// end switch

            } while (choice != 'Q');

            lowerClassmanWriter.close();

            upperClassmanWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e)

        {
            System.out
                    .println("The program has encountered an error.  Please notify your Systems Administrator"
                            + " of this error. " + e);
        }

    }// end

}// end class
```

Comment: What is your current output and your desired output.

Comment: The output I am getting is this:The lower classmen are:  Message: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
Student Records 
To enter student records, type S.  For a report, type R.  To exit, type Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

```
classStanding = "ID Number " + idNum + ", Student Name: "
                        + last + ", " + first + " Credit Hours: "
                        + totalCredits;

array = classStanding.split(",");

totalCredits = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);
```

array only has 3 indices. If you want the last, you should call `array[2]` instead of `array[3]`.

Also `array[2]` is a String `" Credit Hours: " + totalCredits;`. You can't parse that. You should use `split` again to get just the `totalCredits`